# Import error from a blueprint file in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have file structure like this:

```
endpoints/
    __init__.py
    apartments.py
services/
    __init__.py
    apartment.py
__init__.py
app.py
```

in app.py

```
from flask import Flask

from endpoints.apartments import apartments_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(apartments_blueprint, url_prefix='/apartments')
```

in apartments.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, request
from services.apartment import ApartmentService

apartments_blueprint = Blueprint('apartments', __name__)


@apartments_blueprint.route('/create', methods=['POST'])
def create():
    print(request.data)
    ApartmentService.create_apartment('asdf')
```

However, when I run this `flask run` it says:

`ImportError: No module named services.apartment`

Answer (score 0):

Services is a relative import from `endpoints.apartment`. Adding a leading `..` to the import should correct your error:

```
from ..services.apartment import ApartmentService
```

Since Python3 requires relative imports to be explicit, and you might not always execute this from the package directory, you should also add a leading `.` to your import in `app.py`:

```
from .endpoints.apartments import apartments_blueprint
```

To make it explicit and avoid any additional issues.